# NullPointerException - Database Cursor in Android - Workaround

Tags: android, database, nullpointerexception

I'm having an issues with a null pointer exception that I'm trying debug/work around in the following code.  I'm trying to initialize the waypointCursor to null and I need to check if it is equal to null later in the code.  Do this though is giving me a NullPointerExeception.  I need help trying to work around it.  Here is the following code and details.

Here is the code that is calling the method:

```
private void displayCursor(Cursor tracksCursor)
{
  UnitsI18n mUnits;
  mUnits = new UnitsI18n( this, new UnitsI18n.UnitsChangeListener()
  {
     @Override
     public void onUnitsChange()
     {
         //Do Nothing
     }
  } );

  Log.i(TAG, "TRACKS CONTENT URI:"+Tracks.CONTENT_URI);
  StatisticsCalculator stats = new StatisticsCalculator(this, mUnits, this); 

  //UNCOMMENT THIS ONCE I FIGURE OUT WHAT IS GOING ON
  if (Tracks.CONTENT_URI != null) { 
      stats.updateCalculations(Tracks.CONTENT_URI);
      //stats.updateCalculations(Uri.withAppendedPath(Tracks.CONTENT_URI, TRACKURI));
  }
```

Here is the code in StatisticsCalculator that is where the NullPointerException is happening:

```
public void updateCalculations( Uri trackUri )
{
  mStarttime = -1;
  mEndtime = -1;
  mMaxSpeed = 0;
  mAverageActiveSpeed = 0;
  mMaxAltitude = 0;
  mMinAltitude = 0;
  mAscension = 0;
  mDistanceTraveled = 0f;
  mDuration = 0;
  long duration = 1;
  double ascension = 0;

  ContentResolver resolver = mContext.getContentResolver();

  Cursor waypointsCursor = null;
  try
  {
     waypointsCursor = resolver.query( 
           Uri.withAppendedPath( trackUri, "waypoints" ), 
           new String[] { "max  (" + Waypoints.TABLE + "." + Waypoints.SPEED + ")"
                        , "max  (" + Waypoints.TABLE + "." + Waypoints.ALTITUDE + ")"
                        , "min  (" + Waypoints.TABLE + "." + Waypoints.ALTITUDE + ")"
                        , "count(" + Waypoints.TABLE + "." + Waypoints._ID + ")" },
           null, null, null );
     if( waypointsCursor.moveToLast() )
     {
        mMaxSpeed = waypointsCursor.getDouble( 0 );
        mMaxAltitude = waypointsCursor.getDouble( 1 );
        mMinAltitude = waypointsCursor.getDouble( 2 );
        long nrWaypoints = waypointsCursor.getLong( 3 );
        waypointsText = nrWaypoints + "";
     }
     waypointsCursor.close();
     waypointsCursor = resolver.query( 
           Uri.withAppendedPath( trackUri, "waypoints" ), 
           new String[] { "avg  (" + Waypoints.TABLE + "." + Waypoints.SPEED + ")" },
           Waypoints.TABLE + "." + Waypoints.SPEED +"  > ?", 
           new String[] { ""+Constants.MIN_STATISTICS_SPEED }, 
           null );
     if( waypointsCursor.moveToLast() )
     {
        mAverageActiveSpeed = waypointsCursor.getDouble( 0 );
     }
  }
  finally
  {
     if( waypointsCursor != null )
     {
        waypointsCursor.close();
     }
  }
```

The line of code in the StatisticsCalculator class(line 75) is this line of code:

```
if( waypointsCursor.moveToLast() )
```

It doesn't like the waypointsCursor being set equal to null on this line:

```
Cursor waypointsCursor = null;
```

Right above the try statement above.  I do need to have it set to null though so I can check if waypointsCursor is equal to null on this line:
    if( waypointsCursor != null )
in the finally statement.

Here is the logcat output:

```
04-12 18:29:16.795: I/OGT.TrackList(6115): TRACKS CONTENT URI:content://com.android.gpstracker/tracks
04-12 18:29:16.795: E/OGT.GPStrackingProvider(6115): Unable to come to an action in the query uri: content://com.android.gpstracker/tracks/waypoints
04-12 18:29:16.795: D/AndroidRuntime(6115): Shutting down VM
04-12 18:29:16.807: W/dalvikvm(6115): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
04-12 18:29:16.915: E/AndroidRuntime(6115): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-12 18:29:16.915: E/AndroidRuntime(6115): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.gpstracker/com.polaris.epicriders.Rides.RidesActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-12 18:29:16.915: E/AndroidRuntime(6115):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
04-12 18:29:16.915: E/AndroidRuntime(6115):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
04-12 18:29:16.915: E/AndroidRuntime(6115):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
04-12 18:29:16.915: E/AndroidRuntime(6115):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
04-12 18:29:16.915: E/AndroidRuntime(6115):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-12 18:29:16.915: E/AndroidRuntime(6115):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-12 18:29:16.915: E/AndroidRuntime(6115):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-12 18:29:16.915: E/AndroidRuntime(6115):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-12 18:29:16.915: E/AndroidRuntime(6115):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-12 18:29:16.915: E/AndroidRuntime(6115):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-12 18:29:16.915: E/AndroidRuntime(6115):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-12 18:29:16.915: E/AndroidRuntime(6115):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-12 18:29:16.915: E/AndroidRuntime(6115): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-12 18:29:16.915: E/AndroidRuntime(6115):     at com.android.gpstracker.actions.utils.StatisticsCalculator.updateCalculations(StatisticsCalculator.java:75)
04-12 18:29:16.915: E/AndroidRuntime(6115):     at com.polaris.epicriders.Rides.RidesActivity.displayCursor(RidesActivity.java:901)
04-12 18:29:16.915: E/AndroidRuntime(6115):     at com.polaris.epicriders.Rides.RidesActivity.displayIntent(RidesActivity.java:880)
04-12 18:29:16.915: E/AndroidRuntime(6115):     at com.polaris.epicriders.Rides.RidesActivity.access$6(RidesActivity.java:832)
04-12 18:29:16.915: E/AndroidRuntime(6115):     at com.polaris.epicriders.Rides.RidesActivity$8.onCheckedChanged(RidesActivity.java:198)
04-12 18:29:16.915: E/AndroidRuntime(6115):     at android.widget.RadioGroup.setCheckedId(RadioGroup.java:174)
04-12 18:29:16.915: E/AndroidRuntime(6115):     at android.widget.RadioGroup.access$600(RadioGroup.java:54)
04-12 18:29:16.915: E/AndroidRuntime(6115):     at android.widget.RadioGroup$CheckedStateTracker.onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup.java:358)
04-12 18:29:16.915: E/AndroidRuntime(6115):     at android.widget.CompoundButton.setChecked(CompoundButton.java:129)
04-12 18:29:16.915: E/AndroidRuntime(6115):     at com.polaris.epicriders.Rides.RidesActivity.onCreate(RidesActivity.java:222)
04-12 18:29:16.915: E/AndroidRuntime(6115):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
04-12 18:29:16.915: E/AndroidRuntime(6115):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
04-12 18:29:16.915: E/AndroidRuntime(6115):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Post your ContentProvider's `query()` method, so we can see why it's returning null.

Comment: The query() method is part of the ContentResolver class that is part of the Android SDK.

Answer (score 0):

if the query has no results to return then the return value will be null. it is good practice to check that the return value of a query is not null before using it as a cursor. so in your case you can have the following right after the query

```
if(waypointsCursor == null)
    return null;
```

or if you don't want to return, then wrap the ensuing code in an if block

```
if(waypointsCursor == null){
    if( waypointsCursor.moveToLast() )
    ...
 }
```